# Having issues with a returning 0 with a user input value could be any number

Tags: java

I am working on a debugging assignment for class, I have finished the debugging parts of it and he has hidden the last debug the returning of the zero in the output. No matter what you type in for the input it will always return zero.

I have a feeling it is related to the "public void display() method" If someone can give me some guidance on where I can look and troubleshoot that would be very appreciated.

```
// A PhoneBook is a Book with a city
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DebugPhoneBook {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String area;
    int pages;

    System.out.println("Enter city for phone book");
    area = input.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter number of pages in " + area + "'s phone      book");
    pages = input.nextInt();

    PhoneBook pb = new PhoneBook(area, pages);

    pb.display();
 }
 }

 //***************************************************
 //**  PhoneBook class starts below this box   **
 //***************************************************
  class PhoneBook extends Book {



  final private String area;
  final private String size;


   public PhoneBook(String city,int pages ) {
    super(pages);
    area = city;
    if (pages > 300) {
        size = "big";
    } else {
        size = "small";
    }
    }

   public void display() {
    System.out.println("The phone book for " + area
            + " has " + pages + " pages.\nThat is a "
            + size + " phone book.");
   }
}

  //******************************************************
  //** Book class starts below this box                 **
  //******************************************************
 class Book {

 protected int pages;

 public Book(int pgs) {
    pgs = pages;
 }

 public int getPages() {
    return pages;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your "professor" shouldn't suggest you use a String for the size. An `Enum` is the correct choice, for many reasons, not the least of which is someone could set it to `"foo"`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Book` constructor doesn't store the value you pass to it:

```
public Book(int pgs) {
    pgs = pages;
}
```

The default value of `pages` (or any `int`) is `0`.  Not to mention that setting `pgs` like that doesn't actually do anything as it's passed by value to the method.

I suspect you meant to do that the other way around:

```
public Book(int pgs) {
    pages = pgs;
}
```

Comment: That's why I prefer to go with `public Book(int pages) { this.pages = pages; }` - it avoids confusion and the need to come up with two names for the same thing.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks so much. So i see what you mean. The protected int pages is just something for the "get" to return correct and the acutal value is being set in the book constructor. Or am i still misunderstanding.

Comment: @MichaelLopez: Your description sounds a bit weird, so you may indeed be misunderstanding something.  The `pages` variable is how the class retains that value.  The constructor is being supplied the value to set to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the constructor of `Book`
Instead of

```
public Book(int pgs) {
    pgs = pages;
}
```

it should be

```
 public Book(int pgs) {
    pages = pgs;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The professor set up the code like this and had us correct the minor issues with the code. Thanks to your responses it fixed the issue.

```
//***************************************************
//**  PhoneBook class starts below this box   **
//***************************************************
class PhoneBook extends Book {

private String area;
private String size;

PhoneBook(int pages, String city) {
    super();
    area = city;
    if (pages > 300) {
        size = "big";
    } else {
        size = "small";
    }
}

public display() {
    System.out.println("The phone book for " + area
            + " has " + pages + " pages.\nThat is a "
            + size + " phone book.");
}
}

//******************************************************
//** Book class starts below this box                 **
//******************************************************
class Book {

protected int pages;

public Book(int pgs) {
    pgs = pages;
}

public int getPages() {
    return pgs;
}
}
```